# Laravel localization package throws MethodNotAllowedHttpException on POST request

Tags: php, laravel

I use this package for localization https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization and it works fine in most cases except with one POST request.

When I try to access:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix'     => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'auth'],
    ],
    function () {
    Route::post('bsSearch', 'BrandSpendingsController@search')->middleware('premium');
}
```

I get an `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` ... When I switch it to `GET` it works fine... However it works for english language. If I switch the url to http://localhost/de/bsSearch, it throws an error.

```
Route::get('bsSearch', 'BrandSpendingsController@search')->middleware('premium');
```

I am really not sure why because this one works fine and it is a `POST` method as well:

```
Route::post('editUserProfile/{id}', 'UserController@edit');
```

I use Laravel 5.3.

**EDIT**

The english url works because I've set `'hideDefaultLocaleInURL'  => true,` in `laravellocalization.php` and when it hides the "en" prefix in URL. If i set it to `false`, it throws an error for English as well.

Comment: Try to use PUT method instead of POST, don't forget to change the method type in your form

Comment: Not working :(.

Comment: Have you changed the route ? like this :
Route::put('editUserProfile/{id}', 'UserController@edit');

Comment: Yes. And editUserProfile works as POST request, but bsSearch doesn't.

Comment: I have same problem in plugin mcamara/laravel-localization with any method except GET. With GET everthing works but with POST, PUT, DELETE it redirects to GET

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#methodnotallowedhttpexception) is an answer

1. it is better to localize only GET routes by puting them to localized group and don't put there another routes
2. if you need to localize another methods like POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, you should localize your url as described [here](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#post-is-not-working)